# Managed class types as type of type parameter T (Error C2670)

Tags: .net, generics, visual-c++, c++-cli, generic-collections

I want to create a generic function returning a collection of type `ObservableCollection<T>^`. Callers pass a managed class type for type parameter `T`.
Here is one of my tries of the generic function, after that explanations of other classes used:

```
generic<class T>
    where T:CAnimal, gcnew()
        ObservableCollection<T>^ GetItems(AnimalType animalType, int count)
    {
        ObservableCollection<T>^ animals = gcnew ObservableCollection<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (animalType == Dog)
            {
                CDog^ dog = gcnew CDog(i, count - i);
                //CAnimal^ dog = gcnew CDog(i, count - i);
                //T dog = gcnew CDog(i, count - i);
                //T^ dog = gcnew CDog(i, count - i);

                animals->Add(dog);
            }
            //else if (animalType == Cat) { ... }
            //...
        }

        return animals;
    }
```

Because I tried nearly 1632 ways to make that function work I can't tell you why I've implemented it as is :-/

**Class `CAnimal`** is the base class for **`CDog`** (assume there are more animals, too). **`AnimalType`** is an enumeration intended to be used in the function above to determine the correct class type for instantiating and adding to the collection:

```
ref class CAnimal
{
public:
    CAnimal(){}
    CAnimal(int _age) { age = _age; }
    int age;
};

ref class CDog : CAnimal {
public:
    CDog(){}
    CDog(int _age, int _other)
        :CAnimal(age), other(_other) {}

    int other;
};

enum AnimalType
{
    Dog,
    Cat,
    Fish,
    // ...
};
```

Furthermore there's a parent class holding `ObservableCollection`'s of dogs, cats, and so on:

```
ref class CZoo
{
private:
    ObservableCollection<CDog^>^ dogs;

public:
    CZoo()
    {
        dogs = GetItems<CDog^>(AnimalType::Dog, 3);
    }
};
```

The compiler throws the following error:

> error C2670: 'System::Collections::ObjectModel::Collection::Add' :
>   the function template cannot convert parameter 1 from type 'CDog ^'

**Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

**!!! SOLUTION !!!**

Based on [David Yaws' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099993/managed-class-types-as-type-of-type-parameter-t-error-c2670/32100365#32100365) I ended up moving the constructor parameters into a new function called `Initialize` and removed the `enum AnimalTypes`. The final code was changed to the following:

```
ref class CAnimal
{
internal:
    virtual void Initialize(int _age, int _other)
    {
        age = _age;
        other = _other;
    }

public:
    int age;
    int other;
};

ref class CDog : CAnimal {};
ref class CCat : CAnimal {};

generic<class T>
    where T:CAnimal, gcnew()
        ObservableCollection<T>^ GetItems(int count)
    {
        ObservableCollection<T>^ animals = gcnew ObservableCollection<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            T animal = gcnew T();
            animal->Initialize(i, count - i);
            animals->Add(animal);
        }

        return animals;
    }

ref class CZoo
{
private:
    ObservableCollection<CDog^>^ dogs;
    ObservableCollection<CCat^>^ cats;

public:
    CZoo()
    {
        dogs = GetItems<CDog^>(3);
        cats = GetItems<CCat^>(7);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without leaving a comment. That's fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remove the stuff not relevant to the error, here's what we've got:

```
generic<class T>
where T:CAnimal, gcnew()
ObservableCollection<T>^ GetItems()
{
    ObservableCollection<T>^ animals = gcnew ObservableCollection<T>();

    animals->Add(gcnew CDog());

    return animals;
}
```

Now, what happens if this is invoked as `GetItems<CCat^>()`? Now you're trying to put a `CDog` into a list of `CCat`, and that won't work. That's what the error message is saying: `CDog` may not be able to be converted to `T`.

If you want to do this, there's a couple possible solutions:

- You could return a list of `CAnimal` instead. `CDog` is always valid to put into a list of `CAnimal`.
- You could change how you initialize the list of `T`.

I'd recommend the latter, and do something like this:

```
generic<class T>
where T:CAnimal, gcnew()
ObservableCollection<T>^ GetItems(int count)
{
    ObservableCollection<T>^ animals = gcnew ObservableCollection<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        T animal = gcnew T();
        animal->Initialize(i, count-i);
        animals->Add(animal);
    }

    return animals;
}
```

- Because you've got the `gcnew()` constraint, that means that the class has a zero-parameter constructor, and you're allowed to call it using just type `T`.
- Move the constructor parameters you currently have into a method defined on `CAnimal`. This way you can call it on any `T`.
- I removed the enum parameter. You don't need it; you're already specifying which animal you want via the generic.

  - I recommend you do this change regardless of how you implement this. Otherwise, you'll have to consider what things like `GetItems<CDog^>(AnimalType::Cat, 3)` should do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and various ways of solving my problem. I integrated the final code into the question. The only change made to your suggested generic function was changing `T^ animal = ...` into `T animal = ...`, since indiretion on generic type parameters are not allowed (error C3229).

Comment: I was away from a compiler when I typed that up, thanks for the correction. Fixed.